# Can't get much working in Ubuntu Studio (19.04)

Tags: ubuntu-studio, midi

My gear:

Yamaha PSR-175 keyboard

Alesis io2 audio interface

Shitty speakers connected via line-in on PC

I can basically launch LMMS, Ardour, etc. Even managed to get Rakarrack to play my guitar, although the signal was system audio capture mixed with the FX in Rakarrack, so it sounded like two guitars.

All I want to do is play my keyboard through my PC and use it as a midi controller to record music in LMMS or Ardour. I can't get the keyboard connected to ANYTHING. It's currently connected to my io2 interface. Audio output in QJackCtl is routed to system output (speakers), input is coming from the io2 interface. For the life of me, I can't get the connection working in any synth, keyboard, etc.

I've read through the official Ubuntu Studio audio production guide, as well as the midi setup guide with Ardour, but I still can't get any connections working. Is there any FOOL PROOF, IDIOT PROOF guide to setting this up for me? Do I just not have the right gear? Any help is appreciated, as I'm entirely new to audio production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same thing last weekend installing Ubuntu 19.04.
I followed the official manuals and guides telling me for instance to use Rygel to share music like you probably tried too. Only to find out nothing is actually working or simple to make working. Sharing music on Ubuntu 19 is impossible without at least a degree in computer sciences.
Thankfully I have, and found the problems are missing packages that have been known about for months by insiders but no one does anything to redeem the issue. Users complain and the people responsible complain about the users.
As music sharing is the most basic part of any Ubuntu installation for music lovers like you I assume the other tasks you are trying to accomplish on your Ubuntu 19 are doooooomed.

I erased my disk and installed Ubuntu **18.04.2 LTS** in 15 minutes, got updates and everything setup and working one hour later.

Ubuntu is the best OS there is for what you want, there is just something very wrong with Ubuntu 19. Same thing happened with DOS 6.21, just a version we all want to forget about.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I had a feeling the problem might lie in 19.04.  I have no problem with going back to 18.04, so I'll try that out.